# Map two entities with different validation requirements to a single table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Is it possible to map two entities to a single table (table per hierarchy) but impose different validation requirements on them? For the most part they are the same thing though.

```
public class Email
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public String Message { get; set; }
}

public class Tweet
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(140)]
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

And then have both these entities map to a single table:

```
Table: Messages

Id int IDENTITY
Discrimator string
Message nvarchar(4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible because your two classes cannot be mapped to one table at all. It would require base class defining both `Id` and `Message` and two empty classes derived from that base class. Shared properties must be defined in a base class = they are defined only once and have only one attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just have a base class and then perform some validation on top for the message length based on the discriminator.